# Throwed a NullPointerException: The fragment has been removed from FragmentManager in testing

Tags: android-testing

```
@Test
    fun testBottomSheetShown(){
        val args = Bundle().apply {
            putString("EXTRA_TITLE", "title")
            putString("EXTRA_CURRENT_VALUE", "choiceOne")
        }
        val scenario = launchFragmentInContainer<ChoicesBottomSheet>(args, R.style.BottomSheetDialog)
        scenario.onFragment { 
            assertEquals(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED, it.lifecycle.currentState)
        }
    }
```

I tried to test my Bottomsheet with fragment scenario but it throws the error below:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: The fragment has been removed from FragmentManager already.

Answer (score 2):

`launchFragmentInContainer` will cause the `ChoicesBottomSheet` to reach the RESUME state.

> The fragment has been removed from FragmentManager already

The above error is thrown if the Fragment is already destroyed, and you are trying to access it. So I believe that your BottomSheet fragment is dismissed during its flow to RESUME state. Please check if you have a `dismiss()` call somewhere in your BottomSheet code, that is getting called before your fragment reaches the `onResume()` call.